# How to install programms on the multiple partitions?

Tags: software-installation, mount, ssd

I'm using Elementary on notebook with 1TB HDD and 16GB SSD. I've installed Elementary on SSD and cut HDD into two partitions: one with windows in NTFS and other in ext4 as additional space for documents and programms. How can i install programms in that partition (or, maybe, mount that partition as a part of / directory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use two ext4 partitions of your HDD, one for programs and mount it as`/usr` and the second one for user documents and settings and mount it as `/home`.